# MySQL IFNULL still returns NULL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the total value in the column *mutations*. When there is no data in the column the statement returns `NULL`.

I want to replace the returned `NULL` with *0.00*.

I am trying to implement the IFNULL function in my SQL statement (I am using MySQL). When I execute the statement I still get `NULL`.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Here is my full statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(SUM(IFNULL(mutations,'0.00')),2)) AS total
FROM scu_statement 
WHERE type='2'
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `scu_statement` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mutations` decimal(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: can you post the `scu_statement` table schema? I don't think the problem is in the `IFNULL` function: if you run this [`SELECT CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(SUM(IFNULL(NULL,'0.00')),2)) AS total`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cJFfUwVrJ8L9NZV75WbwVg/0) it runs fine. Why do you say that IFNULL returns NULL? How could you support this assumption?

Comment: When I use `SELECT CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(SUM(mutations),2)) AS total` for `type='1'` the statement returns data. `type='2'` of the only type that is empty.

Comment: Since the column is declared `NOT NULL` it can never be null.

Comment: Show us an example that we can produce, with data. At the moment your assertions are suspect for a few reasons (including what Barmar observed).

Comment: You are right. In this case there is no row with `type='2'`. But I still want that the script returns the data 0.00

Comment: Now that you have posted the schema I've to support what @Barmar says.

Comment: If there are no rows, the query doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: Are you talking about using it in a correlated subquery, or left-joining with a grouped query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the return set has no rows, *SUM()* returns *NULL* so just add *IFNULL* function to check whether *SUM* returns *NULL*

```
SELECT CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(IFNULL(SUM(mutations), 0),2)) AS total
FROM scu_statement 
WHERE type='2'
```

Verification example:

```
SELECT CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(IFNULL(SUM(mutations), 0),2)) AS total
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS mutations) as t1 LIMIT 0) as q
```

---

SUM Function ignores NULL value. You can verify it in this way:

```
SELECT SUM(X)
FROM (
             SELECT 1 AS X
             UNION SELECT 10 AS X
             UNION SELECT NULL AS X    
         ) AS q
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SUM()` function ignores null values, and sum up all non-null values.

There are two reasons why `SUM()` might return null:

- All rows have a null value.
- No rows are found.

Since your `mutations` column is `NOT NULL`, it cannot be the first reason, so it's because no rows were found.

To prevent null, you need to call `IFNULL` *outside* the `SUM`:

```
SELECT CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(IFNULL(SUM(mutations),0),2)) AS total
FROM scu_statement 
WHERE type='2'
```

Comment: If no rows are found, it won't return null, it will return an empty result set.

Comment: @Barmar When you apply an aggregating function without a `GROUP BY`, the query will always return exactly one row.